# Redirecting to certain part in another page using HTML, JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```html
<nav>
  <div class='container-fluid'>
      <h1 class='logo'>Logo</h1>
      <ul class='list-unstyled naving'>
          <li><a href='index.html'>Home</a></li>
          <li><a href='about.html'>About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href='#contact'>Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I made a template of many pages, the home page only has a section "contact me", the navbar  has links to other pages like about and others, also navbar has the link to the part "contact me".

When I am in the home page and click on "contact me" in the navbar, the page scroll to the section normally.

I need, when I am in the other pages that has not the "contact me" section, when I click on the "contact me" in navbar the home page is open to the section "contact me".

So how could I do that with HTML or JavaScript, jQuery

Comment: You should need some js to check the url to know if you have to scroll down or change to the webpage that have the contact me part and then access that part of the page

Comment: It would be great if you could provide us with a [mre] of what you've tried, any research you've done on the subject, etc. See [ask] for more information on what most Stack Overflow answerers are looking for from questions.

Comment: Use anchors <div id="contact_me"></div> then, no matter what page you're browsing, just set your link to <a href="index.php#contact_me"">Contact me</a>

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
<a href= "http://mywebsite.com/HomePage/#ContactMe">Contact Me</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOcr7.jpg)i try this code and it works

```html
<a href="index.html#contact">Contact<a>
```

the name of page followed by the id without spaces, without /

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <nav>
  <div class='container-fluid'>
      <h1 class='logo'>Logo</h1>
      <ul class='list-unstyled naving'>
          <li><a href='index.html'>Home</a></li>
          <li><a href='about.html'>About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href='index.html#contact'>Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```